# Unity short Black Screen after loading first scene

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, screen, splash-screen

Scenes:

1.Splash, 
one image with the `IEnumerator Start()` code as described below.

2.Menu,
Canvas UI with a few buttons and a some gameobjects in the scene as background. Camera has a tonemapping and depth of field script.

Stats: Batches 96, tris 20.4k, 41.5k

3.Main
Main scene of the game.

Bug, happend on android device and on pc in the editor:

1.Splash scene loads the menu scene using:

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    AsyncOperation async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Menu");

    while (!async.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;

    }
}
```

2.The canvas UI of the Menu scene appears with a black background, the gameobjects in the scene are not visible, for a few seconds.

3.The canvas UI + the scene is visible.

Same bug happens when the Menu scene is loaded from the Main scene.

Unity version = 2017.3.0f3
Using vuforia in the main scene.

EDIT:

I disabled all the objects and camera effects in the Menu scene except for a plane and the canvas, the canvas still appears a few seconds before the plane.

To describe the bug better, the camera seems to active a second after the canvas UI is shown.

EDIT2:

I created a new camera in the menu scene and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my fix by adding an AR camera to the scene and disabling the the VuforiaBehavior component which was making the black screen when the scene was loading.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had checked Split Application Binary in Publishing settings to be able to upload my game to Play Store. (Play Store does not accept apk files to be bigger than 100mb, so you split your big apk into a smaller apk & a obb file)

[image]

However, if you do that, you need to put both your .apk and .obb files to specific folders in your phone, when you are manually testing the game.

.obb needs to be in a specifically named folder, with a specific name, as explained here: http://graphicdna.blogspot.com/2017/06/manually-copying-unitys-apk-and-obb.html

Shortly, name should be in the format:

```
main.[FIRST_PART_OF_VERSION_NUMBER].[PACKAGE_NAME].obb
```

Where [FIRST_PART_OF_VERSION_NUMBER] is the highest digit of the version number you can find in the Player Settings. For instance, if your version is 1.0.0, [FIRST_PART_OF_VERSION_NUMBER] is 1.

And [PACKAGE_NAME] is the package name specified in the same screen, right above the version number.

The game will expect to find that OBB file in a location like:

```
[INSTALL_LOCATION]\Android\obb\[PACKAGE_NAME]
```

Where [PACKAGE_NAME] is the same value described above, and INSTALL_LOCATION refers to whether the game is installed in the internal memory or the external SD-Card (this depends on your own settings).